# Trigger jQuery form validation only if form has already been submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, validation

Unobtrusive validation is based on the idea that you *don't* do form validation until the form has been submitted by the user; once that's happened, if something is invalid on the form, then each field is immediately validated once the user has changed it.

What I want to do is trigger validation on a form element "unobtrusively" - that is, *only* validate the form element if the user has already tried to submit the form.  So I can trigger the validation of an element (I do it when a certain checkbox is changed) like so:

```
$('#chkNoPersonId').change(function(){
    $('#lstPersonId').valid();
});
```

But the trouble is that that will *always* cause `lstPersonId` to be validated and an error displayed when invalid, *even if the user hasn't yet submitted the form once*.  I want it to only be validated once the user has tried to submit the form.  Is there some value I can check to see whether the user has tried to submit the form yet, or some other way I can achieve this behaviour?

Comment: altough I don't get your question right I try to guess. There is a submit() eventhandler which can be used like this: 

$('#myForm').submit(function(){ 
  //Do stuff once the form has been submitted 
});

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a flag on submit button to identify form submit has been already clicked or not.
ex:

```
$('#submitButn').click(function(){
   $(this).attr('data-submitted','true');
});
```

Than in each validation of input check weather that flag is true or not and perform your validation logic.

```
$('#chkNoPersonId').change(function(){
  if( $('#submitButn').attr('data-submitted')=='true'){
   $('#lstPersonId').valid();
  }
});
```

On clear or reset of form you can remove that attribute

```
 $('#submitButn').removeAttr('data-submitted');
```

Comment: I actually ended up using jQuery's `data` functionality (`.data('submitted', true)` on form submit) instead of `attr` to remember when the form had been submitted, but I basically used this solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using using the `submit` event handler?

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    //validate here
});
```

**source:**
http://api.jquery.com/submit/