# How to change form validation on change of checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

inputs of my form takes value based on a regex. There is a checkbox. If that checkbox is checked regex/validation rule/message will be changed too for same input. I have achieved that by checking `if ($('#is_active').is(':checked')) { ... }` condition. But, I need it at run time too.

**Action 1:**

[image]

**Action 2:**

[image]

May be, `change(function() {})` for the checkbox can achieve this. But, at first time when `change` event won't triggered, I need to check the `is(':checked')` too may be. But, I don't understand how to add/remove success/error/highlighted class/state for input based on the validation plugin in run time (checkbox changed event)! Please, take a look on my fiddle and help me to achieve this in a better way.

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/0vjdrj5z/)

Comment: You should be posting your relevant code in the question, and not rely solely on jsFiddle.

Comment: Wrong approach.  Live validation with a conditional dependency belongs inside of the `rules` object; there is no need to create a new method.  Certainly no need to manually add/remove success/highlight/etc. when done properly.  See code in linked duplicate.

Comment: Actually, there will be multiple custom methods. If all those are inside the rules, it would be messed. That's why, I had to add method manually. And, with due all respect, I don't think this is a duplicate question. The purpose of the two question's is different.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  If I understand correctly, you simply need to capture the change event of the checkbox and check if the form is valid.

```
$('#is_active').change(function() {
        $("#custom-form").valid();
});
```

Try this updated fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/LrcL3zg6/

Comment: Yes, you're right! I was looking for this. But, there is only one problem in this fiddle. After page loading, if I tick the checkbox at first, the error message has come (required state). But, I didn't touch the input still. https://i.imgur.com/TCHqK6m.jpg

Comment: Could you put a submit button on your form and then continue in the manner suggested in the following question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734177/trigger-jquery-form-validation-only-if-form-has-already-been-submitted

Comment: I have to put submit button anyway. But, the form needs to be validated at run time.